# Palindrome Index - Python

Tags: python, palindrome

Needing help with a program that is intended to return the index of a key to be deleted for a word that is one key off a palindrome (reads same front to back with whitespace removed). If already a palindrome or two + keys off it just returns none. The program works fine for most except for a word like 'reefer'. Instead of returning the index of the first 'e' to be deleted, it is returning the index of 'f'. This is because the code that checks if the letter after in the reverse direction is the same in the forward direction finds that there is an 'e' in both directions and therefore the 'f' must be wrong. 
There must be a better way of doing this, or can anyone think of a way to fix this?

```css
def near_palindrome(word):    
    string = list(word.replace(' ', ''))
    is_pal = is_palindrome(string)
    if is_pal == False:
        result = []
        for char in string:
            rev_index = len(string) - string.index(char) - 1       
            if string[string.index(char)] != string[rev_index]:
                if string[string.index(char) + 1] == string[rev_index]:
                    result.append(string.pop(string.index(char)))                
                elif string[string.index(char)] == string[rev_index - 1]:
                    result.append(string.pop(rev_index))                    

        if len(result) == 1 and is_palindrome(string) == True:
            for s in word:
                if s == result[0]:
                    return word.index(s)

def is_palindrome(word):
    if word == word[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

```
                return word.index(s)
```

def is_palindrome(word):
    if word == word[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

Comment: What's wrong with the current behavior? `reeer` is a palindrome, after all. Do you want it to remove the first letter that would make it a palindrome? Or do you want it to prefer dictionary words?

Comment: I want it to remove the first instance that would make it a palindrome :)

Answer (score 2):

Following code:

1. Finds first key as requested
2. Runs ~4X faster than posted code

[Inspired by](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-character-string-make-palindrome/)

**Code**

```
def is_palindrome(string, low, high):
  " Check if substring from low to high is palindrome " 
  a = string[low:high+1]
  b = a[::-1]

  return a == b

def near_palindrome(string): 
  " Returns index of letter to remove to make palindrome None otherwise "
  low = 0
  high = len(string) - 1

  # loop untill low and high cross each other 
  while low < high: 
    # If both characters are equal then 
    # move both pointer towards respecive ends 
    if string[low] == string[high]: 
        low += 1
        high -= 1
    else: 
        # Check if skipping str[low] makes the whole string a palindrome

        if is_palindrome(string, low + 1, high): 
          return low

        # Check if skipping str[high] makes the whole string a palindrome 
        if is_palindrome(string, low, high - 1): 
          return high

        return None

  # We reach here when complete string will be palindrome 
  # So not a near one
  return None
```

**Test**

```
for s in ['reefer', "tanna", "atnna", "cilvic", "annas"]:
  index = near_palindrome(s)
  if index is not None:
    print(f'string {s}, index {index}, key {s[index]}')
  else:
    print(f'string {s} is not a near palindrome')
```

**Output**

```
string reefer, index 2, key e
string tanna, index 0, key t
string atnna, index 1, key t
string cilvic, index 2, key l
string annas, index 4, key s
```

**Performance**

Test Summary

1. Timed using timeit
2. Data: lst = ['reefer', "tanna", "atnna", "cilvic", "annas"]
3. number repeats = 10, 000

> - Original post: 0.995 seconds
> - New Code: 0.256 seconds

Test Code

```
def test_posted():
  return [near_palindrome_posted(word) for word in lst]

def test_new():
  return [near_palindrome(word) for word in lst]

from timeit import timeit

count = 10000
lst = ['reefer', "tanna", "atnna", "cilvic", "annas"]

print(timeit(test_posted, number=count))
print(timeit(test_new, number=count))
```

Comment: Looks like it's failing/inaccurate in some edge cases, with strings around/over 100k characters in length. Unfortunately HackerRank's not allowing me to see the specifics on these test cases.

Comment: @LarryCai -- is this the [Hackerrank Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/palindrome-index/problem)?

Comment: @LarryCai -- if the above is the Hackerrank problem just change the two `return None` to `return -1`.  In your post, you mention it should return None, but that seems to be incorrect.

Comment: It is the same problem, but the test cases are different for the one in the [One week preparation kit](https://www.hackerrank.com/interview/preparation-kits/one-week-preparation-kit), Mock Test Day 3. I have implemented the modifications (i.e. conditionals for `None` to `-1), and it clears all test cases in the one you linked, but not for the Mock Test. Also it's not even possible to spend Hackos to unlock the failing tests in Mock Tests for specific troubleshooting.

Comment: @LarryCai -- 1) if I don't login to hackerrank, I see a page with day 3 Mock Test, but get an error if I try to load the page. 2) If I login to hackerrank, I don't see any Mock Test, just problems grouped by area.  Thus, perhaps this link is just for you.  You could try going to the leaderboard for the link I gave you to see if other solutions from the leaderboard work (you have access to the leaderboard since your solution worked).

Answer (score 1):

```
    def palindromeIndex(s):
        # Write your code here
        low = 0
        high = len(s) - 1
    
        while (low <= high):
            if s[low] == s[high]:
                low += 1
                high -= 1
            else:
                if isPalindrome(s, low + 1, high):
                    return low
                elif isPalindrome(s, low, high - 1):
                    return high
                else:
                    return -1
    
        return -1
    
    
    def isPalindrome(s, l, r):
        while (l <= r):
            if s[l] == s[r]:
                l += 1
                r -= 1
            else:
                return False
    
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

My code works for the Hackerrank problem mock test 3 of the 1 week preparation section. Just some modifications to the first answer and it clears all test cases!

```
def is_palindrome(string,low,high):
    a=string[low:high+1]
    b=a[::-1]
    return a==b

def palindromeIndex(string):
    low=0
    high=len(string)-1

    while low<=high:
        if string[low]==string[high]:
            low+=1
            high-=1
        else:
            if is_palindrome(string,low+1,high):
                return low
            elif is_palindrome(string,low,high-1):
                return high
            else:
                return -1
    return -1
```